# How does co-editing a Sharepoint Excel Online document work?

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, excel-online

- If I'm using an Excel workbook and editing in the browser (not downloading the document to my PC to make changes offline), will I know if someone else is also editing it at the same time?
- Will the browser boot one of us off, or not let one of us save?
- Will we be able to see the changes they've made?
- If they save their work before mine, will all of mine be lost?

There may be a lot of people editing the same document, and I want to prevent anyone's work from getting written over/lost, or having old versions floating around.

Answer (score 2):

When you open the file from the browser you will have the capability to edit by multiple users at a time.

When it is opened for edit by multiple users you will see names at a top right side of the ribbon. see screenshot below.

[image: image here]

I opened document for edit and at the same time user `demo` is also editing. The cells another user is editing highlights in the different border color. The changes will save all changes automatically and simultaneously.

If the file being checked out before edit from the browser or file opened from the "Excel Application" other user will the warning message says **File has been locked with another user**.

Answer (score 1):

When you select a document in SharePoint there is a ribbon bar that appears which displays many options to the user. One of the options is to "Check out" a document. This means that you can edit it without worrying about anyone else being able to edit it. While it is checked out other users can open the file in read only mode and read it as it was before you started working on it.

There is a second feature called co-authoring that lets multiple people work on one document at once. It does this by allowing users to edit parts of the document that no one else is editing. For example if you have a 3 page document with 8 paragraphs we could have 8 people editing it at once, as long as they were all working on a seperate part of the file. No 2 people can edit the same chunk of text at once.